# How do I get the real index of this user in my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm getting my example from [Vue JS docs](http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#filterBy)

If I have a `v-for` that's filtered, how do I get the *real* index of this user in my array? Not the index of the current iteration, but the index of the item from the array.

```
<div id="filter-by-example">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in users | filterBy 'Jim' in 'name'">
      {{ user.name }}
      {{ $index }} <!--I want Jim's index to be 3, not 0-->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Vue JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#filter-by-example',
  data: {
    users: [
      { name: 'Bruce' },
      { name: 'Chuck' },
      { name: 'Jackie' },
      { name: 'Jim' },
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#filter-by-example',
  data: {
    users: [
      { name: 'Bruce' },
      { name: 'Chuck' },
      { name: 'Jackie' },
      { name: 'Jim' },
    ]
  },
  methods : {
    getIndexOfItem: function(arr, item) {
      return arr.indexOf(item);
 }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="filter-by-example">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in users">
        {{getIndexOfItem(users, user)}} - {{user.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Added a getIndexOfItem method into the methods collection and in the `v-for` passed in the array and item then returned the item index, this seems complex but most other implementations didn't seem to work work.

**Edit 2**

I removed the function inside the methods collection.

```
<li v-for="(user, index) in users | filterBy 'Jim' in 'name'">
```

https://jsbin.com/misagagewo/edit?output

Comment: Your OP works, but not the Edit. Setting the (user,index) pair returns zero for all iterations. Or at least it does in Vue 1.0.

Comment: @danfo try this one https://jsbin.com/nobezurehi/edit?html,js,output it doesn't have the filterBy expression but you could write that into a method

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't. You can do something like this though.

```
<div id="filter-by-example">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in users | filterBy 'Jim' in 'name'">
      {{ user.name }}
      {{ user._index }} 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function fixupObjArray(arr) {
  arr.forEach((e,i) => e._index = i);
  return arr;
}

new Vue({
  el: '#filter-by-example',
  data: {
    users: fixupObjArray( [
      { name: 'Bruce' },
      { name: 'Chuck' },
      { name: 'Jackie' },
      { name: 'Jim' },
    ] )
  }
})
```